# Is there a way to get repo size of a mirror clone using github api?

Tags: git, github, curl, github-api, du

For getting the size using github api, I'm able to do a curl and extract size from it as below.

```
curl -H "Authorization: token <token>" https://api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo> | jq | grep size
```

But, when I do mirror clone of that repo and do `du -sh .` in the repo directory, I see different value.

What am I missing here?

Is there a way to get the mirror clone size using github api instead of cloning it to local and using `du` on it?

Comment: I'm not sure what field `size` means in github's api response. But I guess it could be something like a size of a bare repository. Can you check size of repo on disk if you clone bare repo `git clone --bare`?

Comment: Still getting different value even with `--bare`

Comment: Well, I've taken size of [this repo](https://github.com/sienori/simple-translate) from github api: 11288, --bare + du: 11416. Close enough I think. Size of what do you want exactly, and how precise do you expect it to be?

Comment: What I want exactly? - The total size it takes on my disk space when I do a `mirror` clone. How precise? - I'm fine with approximations too. Just to create a report for the list of repos.

Comment: Why not just do the clone and see? In the time this question has sat here you could have had your answer by now.

Comment: Why not? - because there are thousands of repos for which I need to generate a report before migrating them to GHEC. Cloning all of them to local and checking the disk usage is cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  GitHub doesn't garbage-collect objects by default, so the size of the repository it has on disk may contain many objects which are not used.  As a result, GitHub can't know until it serves a request what data it has on disk will be used to satisfy that request and how it will be deltified and compressed over the connection (and hence, in the resulting packfile in the clone).

In addition, because GitHub may store multiple packs at once, it may store multiple copies of the same objects to ensure the packs are complete.  Thus, what's on disk may be larger than what the clone has.  A future repack may end up making the repository smaller (or possibly larger) than it is now.

The API will provide an approximation of how big the repo is on disk at GitHub, but it isn't a guarantee of what size you'll get in any given situation.

Answer (score 1):

History doesn't have an intrinsic on-disk size, repack results will depend on compression parameters used.

Clones rarely get *everything* from their source (you can ask for a `--mirror` clone to get all the upstream's remote-tracking histories but even that won't get any abandoned lines).

Try `git repack -ad --window-memory=1G --window=100` to very substantially reduce the on-disk size of most repos. If you want to incur large amounts of pain for relatively little further gain, and you've never done it before to this specific repository, this specific clone, add `-f` to the repack options.